# 1-out-of-2 Oblivious Transfer with RSA

Tags: rsa, oblivious-transfer

I'm trying to implement a simple 1-out-of-2 Oblivious Transfer with RSA. I was checking the code and tried to work it step by step. The 2 messages by Alice, let's say, are $m_0 = 7$ and $m_1 = 9$. Bob's decryption turns out to be -8. Can you please help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly? Am I missing $\bmod N$ somewhere?

- $m_0 = 7$, $m_1 = 9$
- $p: 3$, $q: 5$, $\phi: 8$, $N: 15$
- coprime $e: 3$
- $d: 3$
- Public and private keys: $(3, 15)$
- $X_0, X_1: 8, 5$
- Bob's choice: $b=0$, random $k: 22$
- $x_b: 8$
- $v = (8+22^3) \bmod 15 = 6$
- $v: 6$, $k_0: (6-8)^3 \bmod 15 = 7$, $k_1: (6-5)^3 \bmod 15 = 1$
- $m_0+k_0: 7+7= 14=M_0$
- $m_1+k_1: 9+1= 10=M_1$
- $M_b: 14$
- Bob decrypts: Chosen Message: $17-22 = -8$

Comment: Yes, the question (and the [wikipedia page it now links to](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Oblivious_transfer&oldid=1178477302)) are missing a final reduction modulo $N$.

Comment: That is M0 and M1 that Alice sends to Bob should be computed as modulo N, and in the last step Bob also must do modulo N?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reductions modulo $N$ are missing in the [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/108981/6), for $m_0+k_0$, $m_1+k_1$ (even though they do nothing for the parameters used), and the final $17−22=−8$, which after reduction modulo $N=15$ yields the expected $m_b=7$.

Except for the public key $(e,N)$, everything that's exchanged, and the final decryption, is to be reduced modulo $N$. The final reduction is necessary to consistently get the correct result. The other reductions are necessary to avoid information leak.

The [wikipedia description of RSA-based 1-out-of-2 Oblivious transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Oblivious_transfer&oldid=1189129337#1%E2%80%932_oblivious_transfer) is now hopefully fixed.

Notice that $p$ and $q$ in the question are way too small for security. They should be like 1000-bit (300 decimal digits), rather than 2 or 3-bit (1 decimal digit).

---

##### 1-out-of-2 Oblivious Transfer with RSA

$A$ has two secrets $m_0$ and $m_1$. The protocols sends one of the two to $B$, as decided by $B$, over a public channel, with $A$ not knowing ("oblivious to") which secret $B$ decided to receive. Some **passive** observer does not learn the secrets, or $B$'s choice.

We assimilate bitstrings to non-negative integers per some convention, e.g. big-endian binary.

1. Key setup: $A$ generates (or reuses) an RSA key pair with public key $(e,N)$ and private key $(d,N)$, and makes $(e,N)$ known to $B$. We assume $N$ large enough for security, and $N>\max(m_0,m_1)$.
2. $A$ generates random $x_0$ and $x_1$ uniformly at random in $[0,N)$ and sends $(x_0,x_1)$ to $B$.
3. $B$ secretly chooses $b\in\{0,1\}$, generates random $k$ uniformly at random in $[0,N)$, computes and sends $v=((k^e\bmod N)+x_b)\bmod N$ to $A$.
4. $A$ computes ${m'}_0=(((v-x_0)^d\bmod N)+m_0)\bmod N$, ${m'}_1=(((v-x_1)^d\bmod N)+m_1)\bmod N$, and sends $({m'}_0,{m'}_1)$ to $B$.
5. $B$ computes $m_b=({m'}_b-k)\bmod N$

The protocol is sound (that is, $B$ faithfully gets the desired secret) because in step 4 it holds $(v-x_b)^d\bmod N=k$.

The protocol keeps $b$ perfectly secret from $A$ or an observer because the distribution of $v$ (the only thing sent by $B$) is undistinguishable from a uniformly distributed random over $[0,N)$ even with knowledge of $(e,d,N)$ and $(x_0,x_1)$, because $k$ has this distribution and $k\mapsto k^e\bmod N$ is a bijection.

It looks like if $B$ could learn the other secret $m_{1-b}$, or if an adversary could learn either secret, they could break RSA. However I do not know if we need the hypothesis that $m_0$ and $m_1$ are random and independent (which we could get with random padding as in RSA encryption). Addition of such (or other) info/argument/proof in this community wiki is welcome!